# Как оправить данные введенные в меню расширения в другой файл

Tags: javascript, html, chrome-extension, extension

Пишу расширение, сделал меню к нему в котором пользователь вводит какие-то данные.
Нужно сделать так что бы по клику на кнопку(в меню расширения) эти самые данные помещались на нужную мне страницу.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот манифест и HTML:

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1.3",
  "description": "",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "content/popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["https://google.com/*"],
    "js": ["content/content.js"],
    "css": ["content/qq.css"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }]
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="content/background.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="text">
  <input type="button" id="btnForBalance" value="Send">
  </body
```

Получается, что мне нужно отправить введенные в поле данные кнопкой `send` из файла который работает только с меню расширения в файл, который эти данные вставит на нужную мне страницу. Как это сделать?
Помогите, ибо если я ставлю код, который это делает в мой `js` файл то он пытается взять эти данные из `input` на странице, а не с меню расширения.

Вот структура:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чем в вашем понимании является "меню расширения"?

Comment: @Deliaz это то окошко, которое появляется при клике на иконку расширения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по вашему коду, вы немного запутались в терминологии и назначении API для расширений.

Для решения задачи вам потребуется:

1. **popup** (попап - то, что вы называете "меню расширения")
2. **content-script**

background-скрипт же, в данном случае не требуется.

Набросал работающий пример расширения.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content-script.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }]
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head> 
<body>
    <input type="text" id="data">
    <button id="go">Отправить</button>

    <script src="popup.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#go');
const input = document.querySelector('#data');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const text = input.value; 

    // Ищем активный таб в текущем окне
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(foundTabs) {

        const activeTab = foundTabs[0];

        // Отправляем сообщение в content-script находящейся в этом активном табе
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {text: text}); 
    })
});
```

**content-script.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
    const text = request.text; // принятое сообщение из popup'а

    const input = document.querySelector('#lst-ib'); // для примера используется поле ввода Google.com
    input.value = text;
});
```

### Как это работает

По нажатию на *Отправить* в попапе, сначала происходит поиск активного таба, с целью получить id. 
Далее этому табу (по полученному id) отправляется сообщение с введенным текстом. 

Контент-скрипт принимает сообщение и вставляет в поле ввода.

Обратите внимание:

- директива `"matches": ["<all_urls>"]` запускает контент-скрипт на всех страницах. Рекомендую указать необходимый вам URL-паттерн;
- сообщение можно отправить не только в активный таб; метод [chrome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) позволяет находить табы по множеству параметров;
- после установки расширения, не забудьте перезагрузить вкладку, на которой происходит тестирование, чтобы запустился content-script.

Comment: все работает хорошо, данные приходят, но возник вопрос: можно ли сделать так, что бы данные после ввода в поле и обновлении страницы оставались на странице?

Comment: @МаксимБуяков да, можно запомнить ID такой вкладки. И слушать события [chrome.tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated). При окончании загрузки просто повторить процедуру вставки данных (которые тоже предварительно сохранить).

Comment: простите, не могли бы вы написать что то вроде реализации? я уже пытался сделать это но у меня не получилось

Comment: @МаксимБуяков полагаю это тема для отдельного вопроса.

Comment: я понимаю, но пожалуйста, помогите, это очень важно

Comment: @МаксимБуяков Верю. Создайте новый вопрос с вышеупомятой проблемой и опишите что у вас уже есть из наработок.