# Сохранение измененных значений extension при обновлении вкладки

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Итак, у меня в `popup.html` есть инпут. Если ввести данные, `popup.js` отправляет данные в `content.js` и он уже меняет что то на страннице. Но после обновления изменения на страннице исчезают. Как можно сделать так, что бы они оставались и менялись только если в инпут были введены новые данные?

`popup.html и popup.js`

```js
var input = document.querySelector('#inp');
var text = document.querySelector("#text");
var button = document.querySelector("#btn");

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var inp = input.value;

  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(foundTabs) {

 const activeTab = foundTabs[0];

 chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {text: inp});//отправка значения инпута
    })
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp">
<button id="btn">Send</button>
```

`content.js`:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
     const txt  = request.text; //пришло значение инпута
     chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
          //вставка в html
     });
});
```

И я ввожу в инпут какое то число, нажимаю кнопку но мне в консоль выводит ошибку(см.скрин)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сохраняйте изменения в базу данных и/или храните на сервере.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь localStorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Положим, что для отправки данных из `popup` в `content-script` вы воспользовались [подобным решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/763676/212065).

В таком случае его можно немного доработать. 
Ниже представлен самодостаточный код расширения.

Для отслеживания обновления вкладок и хранения структуры данных предлагаю добавить в расширение [background-скрипт](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages).
Тогда все становится достаточно просто:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content-script.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<input type="text" id="data">
<button id="go">Send</button>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

**popup.js**

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#go');
const input = document.querySelector('#data');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const text = input.value;
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(foundTabs) {
        const activeTab = foundTabs[0];

        // Отправка текста в content-script
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {text: text});

        // Отправка данных в background-скрипт для сохранения
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            tabId: activeTab.id,
            text: text
        });
    })
});
```

**content-script.js**

```
const input = document.querySelector('#lst-ib'); // для примера используется поле ввода Google.com

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
    input.value = request.text;
});
```

**background.js**

```
// Структура вида "id таба -> какой текст вставить"
const observedTabs = new Map();

// Слушаем сообщения из popup.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
    const tabId = request.tabId;
    const text = request.text;

    // Сохраняет text для таба по id
    observedTabs.set(tabId, text);
});

// Отслеживаем изменения в табах
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo) {

    // Если id таба находится в списке отслеживаемых и вкладка завершила загрузку...
    if(observedTabs.has(tabId) && changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
        const text = observedTabs.get(tabId);

        // ..то отправляем в content-script сообщение с текстом (такое же как и в popup)
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {text: text});
    }
});


// Удаляем таб из память в случае, если вкладка закрылась
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(tabId) {
   observedTabs.delete(tabId);
});
```

Обратите внимание что данные в `observedTabs` существуют до перезагрузки расширения или браузера. 
В случае, если вам необходимо иметь постоянный доступ к сохраненным данным, вы можете воспользоваться `localStorage` или [`chrome.storage.local`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).

Comment: спасибо, а не могли бы вы подсказать, как сделать так что бы это работало при нескольких инпутах? То есть можно ли в Map записывать например помимо Text ещё что то, с каким id и как потом его отправить?

Comment: @МаксимБуяков, в `Map` можно положить структуру любой сложности: например `{ id: [ {selector1: text1}, {selector2: text2} ]}`

Comment: `observedTabs.set({tabId : [{selector1: text1}, {selector2: text2} ]);` тоесть запись в `Map` должна быть примерно такая?

Comment: @МаксимБуяков, нет, это просто абстрактная запись. Посмотрите на пример использования `Map`: первым аргументом будет ID вкладки, а вторым массив с объектами. Структура произвольная, но, вероятно, должна содержать селектор для элемента и текст для вставки.

Answer (score 2):

Пример:

```
var input = document.querySelector('#inp');
var text = document.querySelector("#text");
var button = document.querySelector("#btn");

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var inp = input.value;
  text.innerHTML = inp;
  localStorage.setItem('dataForMyInput', inp);
});

window.onload = function() {
    text.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('dataForMyInput') || '';
}
```

Comment: скажите, а как мне это сделать если значения этих инпутов отправляются сначала в другой `js` файл  и там уже скрипт помещает значения в `html`. Добавил немного кода в вопрос

Comment: Ваш код никак не решает озвученную задачу. Полагаю вы не учли, что вопрос задан в контексте браузерных расширений. Однако, предположим, вы приводите пример для страницы `popup.html`, и при ее обновлении данные действительно будут находится в поле ввода этой страницы (popup). Однако вопрос состоит в том, чтобы восстановить данные, введенные на стороннем сайте, посредством `content-script`'a.